# Suitable Laptops

Tags: cisco, networking

Not sure if this topic or question has been asked before but if I was to buy a 2019 top spec macbook pro, would instill be able to connect to Cisco devices, I'll be running windows on it as well but the macbook pro only has USB c connectors and so I'm worried if I get and adaptor and maybe try to connect to a switch or something with a console cable and it won't work

Looking forward to your thoughts, I'm also open to other top spec windows devices.

Comment: There are many USB to serial adapters. Pick one that’s compatible with your Mac

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using usb-serial adapters with PL2303 chipsets for ages. They work fine on Mac. On my latest Macbook Air I've been using a cheap USB-C to all sorts of connections box (HDMI, USB-3, RJ45, VGA, etc), no issues with connecting to serial ports on various brands of devices so far.